# fadeIn() starts over after resizing browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fadein

I was going to give 3 backgrounds to a browser-sized `div` rotating it with jQuery's fading effect. The main problem is whenever I resize the browser, the effect starts over, and I want it to continue wherever it is at the exact moment. I am using Chrome 37. I would appreciate any help or suggestions.

### HTML

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="wrapinside" style="background: url(1.jpg) no-repeat center center;"></div>
    <div class="wrapinside" style="background: url(2.jpg) no-repeat center center;"></div>
    <div class="wrapinside" style="background: url(3.jpg) no-repeat center center;"></div>
</div>
```

### jQuery

```
$(window).load(function(){
$('div.wrapinside').hide();
var dg_H = $(window).height();
var dg_W = $(window).width();

$('.wrap').css({'height':dg_H,'width':dg_W});

function anim() {
    $(".wrap div.wrapinside").first().appendTo('.wrap').fadeOut(3000);
    $(".wrap div").first().fadeIn(3000);
    setTimeout(anim, 6000);
}
anim();})
$(window).resize(function(){window.location.href=window.location.href})
```

### CSS

```
.wrap {
   position: fixed;
   z-index: -1;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   background: #000;
}   

.wrap div.wrapinside {
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   display: none;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   z-index: -1;
   background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: It's something about `$(window).resize(function(){window.location.href=window.location.href})`

Comment: What's that line for? I think the window.location will be upated on it's own, doesn't it?

Comment: Nope, if I take it out, and resize the window, the background stays where it is, and the window is cropping it out. But if I take it out the animation won't start over.

Comment: take a look on my updated answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you could add this to your div.wrapinside css:

```
display: none;
```

After that you won't need this anymore:

```
$('div.wrapinside').hide();
```

Maybe this link could help you, too.
[Change background-image of a div with fade effect every 10 seconds with jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5507518/change-background-image-of-a-div-with-fade-effect-every-10-seconds-with-jquery)

The problem is, that you are updating the value of some variables, but not the size of the div itself, because this line:

```
$('.wrap').css({'height':dg_H,'width':dg_W});
```

is only execute once.

Try this:

```
var dg_H;
var dg_W;
$(window).load(function(){
dg_H = $(window).height();
dg_W = $(window).width();

$('.wrap').css({'height':dg_H,'width':dg_W});

function anim() {
    $(".wrap div.wrapinside").first().appendTo('.wrap').fadeOut(3000);
    $(".wrap div").first().fadeIn(3000);
    setTimeout(anim, 6000);
}
anim();})
$(window).resize(function(){
dg_H = $(window).height();
dg_W = $(window).width();

$('.wrap').css({'height':dg_H,'width':dg_W});
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion of changing the JS code to CSS. The resize function checks the browser's size, and give a `width` and a `height` attribute to the .wrap div to resize the background-image.

Comment: global variables are bad, but try if it helps and than change it.