# How do I change the background image every X seconds?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a `div` that fills the entirety of a page (portfolio style). The `div` has this style:

```
.image-head {
  background: url('http://placehold.it/1920x1080') no-repeat top center fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Basically, what I want to do is every X seconds change the `url` that the `div` points to for it's background image, but I am unsure on how to do this.

My markup currently looks like this:

```
<div class="image-head">
  <div class="centering-hack">
    <h1>Something HTML</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

What's the simplest/best solution here?

Thanks!

*Edit: I'm using Bootstrap 3 if the JS library makes anything easier*

Comment: You mean like [Bootstrap Carousel](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change background-image of a div with fade effect every 10 seconds with jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5507518/change-background-image-of-a-div-with-fade-effect-every-10-seconds-with-jquery)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Make an array** with the images you want to use:

```
var images = [
  "https://www.royalcanin.com/~/media/Royal-Canin/Product-Categories/cat-adult-landing-hero.ashx",
  "https://www.petfinder.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/cat-black-superstitious-fcs-cat-myths-162286659.jpg",
  "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/4d/Cat_March_2010-1.jpg"
]
```

We retrieve the `div` whose background you want to change:

```
var imageHead = document.getElementById("image-head");
```

You can now **use `setInterval`** to change the background image url every second (or whatever interval you want):

```
var i = 0;
setInterval(function() {
      imageHead.style.backgroundImage = "url(" + images[i] + ")";
      i = i + 1;
      if (i == images.length) {
        i =  0;
      }
}, 1000);
```

Here's a live example: https://jsfiddle.net/vvwcfkfr/1/

## Some improvements using functional programming, ES6 and recursiveness:

```
const cats = [
  "https://www.royalcanin.com/~/media/Royal-Canin/Product-Categories/cat-adult-landing-hero.ashx",
  "https://www.petfinder.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/cat-black-superstitious-fcs-cat-myths-162286659.jpg",
  "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/4d/Cat_March_2010-1.jpg"
]

const node = document.getElementById("image-head");

const cycleImages = (images, container, step) => {
    images.forEach((image, index) => (
    setTimeout(() => {
        container.style.backgroundImage = `url(${image})`  
    }, step * (index + 1))
  ))
  setTimeout(() => cycleImages(images, container, step), step * images.length)
}

cycleImages(cats, node, 1000)
```

https://jsfiddle.net/du2parwq/

Comment: Glad to help. The script on the answer below also works.

Answer (score 1):

If I corect underestand your problem you want somthink like 
http://codepen.io/dodekx/pen/BKEbPK?editors=1111

```
var url = ['http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/' ,
        'http://lorempixel.com/400/200/city/'];
curentImageIndex = 0;
setInterval(function(){ 
 console.log(url[curentImageIndex])
 var p = $('.image-head');
  p.css("background","url("+url[curentImageIndex++] + ")");
  if(curentImageIndex>= url.length){curentImageIndex = 0}
 }, 1000);
```

Of course best solution some  jumbutron from jquery plugin or boostrap