# transition background image switch

Tags: javascript, html, css, background-image, transition

i wanted my background image to switch every x seconds so i used this method [How do I change the background image every X seconds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37242754/how-do-i-change-the-background-image-every-x-seconds/37243076#37243076)

but i have one problem with it the switch is very abrubt is there a way to do a transition on this?

```js
var images = [
  "https://www.royalcanin.com/~/media/Royal-Canin/Product-Categories/cat-adult-landing-hero.ashx",
  "https://placehold.it/1920x1080",
  "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/4d/Cat_March_2010-1.jpg"
]

var imageHead = document.getElementById("image-head");

var i = 0;
setInterval(function() {
      imageHead.style.backgroundImage = "url(" + images[i] + ")";
      i = i + 1;
      if (i == images.length) {
        i =  0;
      }
}, 5000);
```

```css
body,html {
 height:100%;
 margin:0;
}

.image-head {
  background: url('https://placehold.it/1920x1080') no-repeat top center fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
}

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

```html
<div id="image-head">
  <div class="centering-hack">
      <h1>Something HTML</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what kind of transition ? fade ?  slide ?

Comment: @TemaniAfif a fade would be best